# Regex: match not-words except token

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

i am trying to match all not-words except `";;;"` in a string, but i don't succeed. The not-words are unknown beforehand. Please see an example as follows:

```
Teststring: 
ab-cd ef;;;gh;ij;;;
Result:
abcdef;;;ghij;;;
```

Does anybody know a smart solution for that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Not-words"? Could you clarify what a "not-word" is?

Comment: By not-words i mean any non alphanumeric character. I want to replace all of those except ";;;"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to get all the parts of the string, you want to keep:

```
/\w+(?:;{3})?/g
```

It matches any number of `Word chars`, followed by a non capturing Group matching `3 semi colons`. This is optional.

You can then create the result by `joining all the matches` to a string.

Comment: Thank you. Can you think of a way to match all the \W characters (except ;;;) in order to replace them?

Comment: Here you get 'what you want', not 'what you don't want', so Theres nothing that should be replaced.